# Cleaning accent in text twitter

Tags: r, diacritics, tm

I am working in text mining with spanish twitts, my problem is that i have the same words but in differents ways (with accent and without accent), example: accion, acción.

I tried to use coding: unicode "UTF-8", but dont work.
my library
library(stringi)
library(twitteR)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: What you could do is create a "data base" of accented characters and what they translate to. Then apply this to individual tweet and "flush" out accented characters. You can for example use `sub`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify clearly what you are trying to do with accessed tweets ( saving in a text file, or as a dataframe etc.) If you are using `UTF-8` encoding it will basically preserve the letter as it is.

```
 con <- file("C:/Dir1/sub_dir1/output/output.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
 write(df, file = con)
```

However, if you are trying to change this accent characters into normal equivalent
The simplest way would be using `iconv`

```
iconv( "acción", to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
>[1] "accion"
```